# cambiar una variable de entorno en cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Buenas como puedo cambiar esto:

```
c:>set

USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrador
```

a esto:

```
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop
```

estoy probando con:

```
setx USERPROFILE "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop"
```

pero sigue sin funcionar alguien me dice como ccambiar el valor??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me sirvió con poner el mismo comando set pero añadiendo el nuevo path:

```
set USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop
```

Como menciona Jose este cambio es temporal es decir una vez que se cierra el cmd se pierde el cambio la respuesta de Jose realiza el cambio permanentemente en el entorno del usuario si deseas realizar el cambio a nivel del entorno del sistema puedes añadir `/m` así:

```
setx USERPROFILE "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop" /m
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente es una variable "delicada" y no puedes modificarla. La puedes buscar en el editor del registro en este path: `Equipo\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`. El estar bajo `Volatile Environment` te indica que por más que la modifiques el sistema la sobreescribirá con los valores ya predefinidos desde el inicio del sistema.

Si lo que buscas es modificar el path de la carpeta de un usuario, [aquí](https://www.top-password.com/blog/rename-user-profile-directory-in-windows/) hay una guía para hacerlo en Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

primero inicia el cmd como administrador de sistema y ejecuta

setx USERPROFILE "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop"

con set tambien lo hara pero no sera permanente!